# Java - Web Application Client & Server (crossdomainpolicy.xml) reply over sockets

Tags: java, networking, cross-domain

OK so here it is:
I have a network chat-client web-based app running in domain A. connecting to a c++ server running on Domain/ip B (there is no webserver there, and my app runs on port 80).
When i run the application in the browser it connects and sends a policy file request data GET /crossdomainpolicy.xml HTTP/1.1 cache control no chache, the browser and so on. all this is about 238 Bytes of data.

What String exactly should i send to the client in order to allow all domains? i have already tried a few but immediatelly after i send them the connection is closed from the client side or its waiting forever.

I am only sending this to the web-app:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

with this i dont get any error but the web-app is waiting for more data which i dont know what it is?
its just not progressing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SIGNED the app and it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK cross-domain requests are denied by browser so you should play with security options of your browser of choice.

I had a similar problem while developing a web app, it's not an easy problem to debug, but for example if you use Firefox and Firebug the error message in the network console is quite obvious.

I hope this helps!